# How to tell gulp.watch to wait until necessary tasks will not be finished before running new cycle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, gulp, frontend

I have an issue with `gulp.watch`.

**TLDR**: 
How to tell `gulp.watch` to wait until necessary tasks will not be finished before running new cycle?

**Reasons**:
I have three tasks: `clean`, `build`, and `watch`.
Task `clean` deletes directory, task `build` produces files in the same directory (`clean` is dependency for `build`).
Task `watch` runs `gulp.watch` on directory and then it runs `build` (that runs `clean`).

But sometimes `watch` task runs new `build` before previous `build` is finished and an error occurs: `build` continues write to directory and `clean` tries to remove directory (of course, `ENOTEMPTY` error happens).

This issue happens when I run `gulp watch` command.

My `Gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var tslint = require('gulp-tslint');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var del = require('del');

var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');
var tsSources = ['app/**/*.ts', 'app/**/*.tsx'];

gulp.task('clean', function() {
  return del(['built']);
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function() {
  return gulp.src(tsSources)
    .pipe(ts(tsProject)).js
    .pipe(rename({extname: '.js'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('built'));
});

gulp.task('tslint', ['clean'], function() {
  return gulp.src(tsSources)
    .pipe(tslint())
    .pipe(tslint.report('msbuild', {
      emitError: false,
      summarizeFailureOutput: false
    }));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['build', 'tslint'], function() {
  return gulp.watch(tsProject.config.filesGlob, ['build', 'tslint']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['build', 'tslint']);
```

Comment: please post some code so that problem can be understood better... In my case it works fine...

Comment: I added my Gulpfile.js that causes an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cleaning the gulp use following code:-

```
gulp.task('clean', function() {
    del.sync([ 
       path.join(__dirname, builtPath, '**/*.js'),
    ], {
       force: true
    });
});
```